# How to create "namespace" in session valid until browser is closed?

Tags: php

For example, I'd like to create "namespace" in session that should be valid until browser is closed.

`$_SESSION['other_data'] = array(...)` - is valid until session is valid
`$_SESSION['valid_until_browser_is_closed'] = array(...)` - is valid until browser is closed.

The only "solution" I see is to create additional cookie that will exprire as browser is closed. And when accessing `$_SESSION['valid_until_browser_is_closed']` we should check existense of this cookie first. Of course we should wrap working with sessions to some kind of class.

Thank you

Comment: And why cannot you simply use a cookie for the second one?

Comment: May I ask what this is for? Doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: why on earth would you have 'valid_until_browser_is_closed' data? that basically is what a session is - its only valid while the browser is open...

Comment: @Kirzilla: Your solution sounds good.

Comment: @ToonMariner, for example. I'd like to unset anything when browser is closed, but I don't like to unset auth stored in session.

Comment: When the browser is closed, the session is no longer valid..

Answer (score 1):

Sessions will automatically expires after 24 minutes of inactivity from the client side. Also the cookie set into the client browser will be deleted as the browser is closed.

To be sure about the cookie being deleted you should try this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0); // lifetime
```

And you should notice that you should call this function before starting the session as documented in the manual:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

With that functions you are editing the `session.cookie_lifetime` parameter in the `php.ini` file which is (quoted from the documentation):

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the
>   lifetime of the cookie in seconds
>   which is sent to the browser. The
>   value 0 means "until the browser is
>   closed." Defaults to 0.

As for the namespace you could use (as already posted by [Jon Skarpeteig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641166/jon-skarpeteig)) a bidimensional array:

```
$_SESSION['namespace']['var'] = 'value';
```

References:

- [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)
- [session.cookie_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing namespaces in the session is to use a two dimensional array like:

```
$_SESSION['namespace']['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Then you can invalidate the namespace by: `unset($_SESSION['namespace']`

Comment: so 'foo' and 'bar' is so popular?? +1

Comment: Uhm, that doesn't answer his question.

Comment: He is not asking for that. Also how could he call `unset()` if he does not know when the user close the browser?